# Talend User Input Form

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-apex, talend, oracleforms

In Oracle there are techniques like Oracle APEX or Oracle Form Builder to allow users to manually input data into forms which is then inserted into the database.

Is there a similar technique to do this with Talend (Data Integration)? Or is there an alternative approach to achieve this?

Thank you,

Peter

Comment: Are you looking for some *talend* products?

They provide **application-integration** offer on their site. But it looks like here is not a good place to advertise this. You could indeed be some commercial guy ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would believe that most users of data integration do not want to have manual inputs - the jobs should be scheduled and run unattended.

If some configuration or variable value is required - i would do it using context files.

So, you are probably looking for another product.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to implement this:

1. Create context variables for the needed felds
2. Use the variables for the table insert
3. Deploy the process as web service
4. Create a HTML form for input and to trigger the web service

As Talend is the integration platform, it was necessary to use its techniques. Additionally this can be used by mobile apps etc.

PS: Commercial guy... please... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is a provision of allowing manual entry of data ;
while setting the context variable you will find a check box ,
a marked check box is consider as prompt by talend which ask the manual entry of value while running the job .